# Javascript enabling input field after disable=true

Tags: javascript, dom-events

html:

```
<label>Label1</label><br>
<input type="text" name="first" onclick="somefunc()"><br>
<label>Label2</label><br>
<input type="text" name="second"><br>
```

Javascript:

```
function somefunc() {
var second = document.getElementsByName('second')[0];
second.disable = true;
}
```

When I click the first input the second is disabled (that was what I want), but when I type something into the first input field, then delete it, the second is still disabled. Is there a way so I can enable it again?
I couldn't find an other event which can solve this.

Comment: Why does a text input react to *click* events at all?

Comment: Please describe exactly the functionality that you want. What are you trying to do, what do you need this for? Give us some context. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `keyup` event on the first input box and check the value of first input box for enabling or disabling second input.

```
<label>Label1</label><br>
<input type="text" name="first" onkeyup="somefunc()"><br>
<label>Label2</label><br>
<input type="text" name="second"><br>
<script>
   function somefunc() {
     var first = document.getElementsByName('first')[0];
     var second = document.getElementsByName('second')[0];
     if(first.value){
       second.disabled = true;
     }else{
       second.disabled = false; 
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! (you missed  the “d”-s from disabled i didnt know why it was not working, but now its perfect)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have missed enabling textbox here. If you can see in previous reply, you just need to re-enable textbox into same state as it was before.